# I want to add string in TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add string in textView.

So i make function init() that implements setText() function.

And i run app, my app is dead.

What is the problem??

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Notice notice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        notice = new Notice();
        Vector<String[]> notice_data = notice.getNotice();

        TextView homeNotice = findViewById(R.id.homeNotice0);
        homeNotice.setText(notice_data.get(0)[0]);
        homeNotice = findViewById(R.id.homeNotice1);
        homeNotice.setText(notice_data.get(1)[0]);
        homeNotice = findViewById(R.id.homeNotice2);
        homeNotice.setText(notice_data.get(2)[0]);
        homeNotice = findViewById(R.id.homeNotice3);
        homeNotice.setText(notice_data.get(3)[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it crash? Include details from logcat.

Comment: Debug your app step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should initialize all the TextViews using

```
findViewById()
```

Then,

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(notice_data.get(0)[0]));
```

TextView accepts only strings, so you must cast it to a string before setting it to TextView